# Is the question "What is the orbit of x under the action of G" equivalent to "What are the possible values of f(x), if f(x) is the action of G on x"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

Title is the question. I'm trying to understand these definitions better.

Is the orbit of an element simply the possible values of the element when a group action is applied to it?

If so, why the abstract definition with equivalence relations and similar? It would seem like a simple concept.

Comment: Yes, that’s right.

Comment: I hope the guy that made the definition knows that it took me 2 hours to understand this.

Comment: You might get a more useful answer if you add the definition you are using to your question. The equivalence relation is relevant in as much as you are partitioning the space that the group is acting on into the orbits, and that is important. Maybe helpful : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set#Partitions_and_equivalence_relations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of action, which is *property-based* and not given by a closed formula, is patterned upon the basic *properties* fulfilled by the "prototypical" action, namely the natural acting (literally) of the bijections on a set $X$ on the elements $x \in X$:
\begin{alignat}{1}
&\iota_X(x)=x, \forall x \in X \\
&(\sigma\tau)(x)=\sigma(\tau(x)), \forall \sigma,\tau \in \operatorname{Sym}(X), \forall x\in X
\end{alignat}
The generalization to abstract groups works because in turn the definition of abstract group is *precisely* patterned upon the properties fulfilled by the set of bijections on a set $X$, endowed with the composition as operation (closure, associativity, identity, inverses). In particular, the "prototypical" version of orbit's definition in abstract group context, namely $O(x)=\{g\cdot x, \space g\in G\}$, becomes in the "native" context of bijection on a set $X$, $O(x)=\{\sigma(x), \space \sigma\in \operatorname{Sym}(X)\}$.